# Laravel - Set active in navigation bar

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following code and it works wonderfully.

My `setActive()` function:

```
function setActive($path, $nav = 'class=active')
{
    return Request::fullUrl() === $path ? $nav : '';
}
```

And how I call it:

```
<li {{ setActive(route('home')) }}>
    <a href="{{ route('mod.banned.index') }}">
        Home
    </a>
</li>
```

So everytime the page is the homepage, it will set it as active.

However, it does not work for subpages if I want it to work. For instance, if I have `/articles/article-1`, `/articles/article-2`, and if no matter what article, I want the article tab to be marked as active.

I want to do something like:

```
setActive(route('articles.index') . '/*') 
// 'articles.index' route = /articles/
// Should be active if -> /anything/after/the/slash/
```

I hope that makes sense.

How can I best do this?

Thanks.

Comment: How about this? <li {{ setActive(route('articles')) }}>
    <a href="{{ route('articles.index') }}">
        Articles
    </a>
</li> . What I want to say is, detailed link could be any thing aflter 'articles/ .. / .. ' etc. But for setActive function just, supply 'articles'.  It may work.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
function setActive($path, $nav = 'class=active')
{
    return preg_match("/".preg_quote($path, '/')."\S*/", Request::fullUrl()) ? $nav : '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/letrunghieu/active
It is helper class for Laravel 4/5 applications to get active class base on current route.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like add a global variable to Views and use it everywhere

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->composer('*', function ($view) {
            $view->with('active_route', \Route::currentRouteName());
        });
    }
}
```

in blade view. it is much simpler. might help someone ;)

```
<ul>
     <li class="{{ $active_route == "home" && "active" }}"> Home </li>
</ul>
```